# javascript function gets called twice

Tags: javascript, forms, href, function-call

I am trying to call a javascript function on clicking a link. Actually i want to submit a form on clicking a link using post method so i am trying to do the below-

```
<a href="javascript:submitCategory(this)" >Handicrafts</a>
```

and in javascript

```
function submitCategory(varthis)
{   
    alert(varthis.value);
}
```

I have few important questions:
1>When i click on the link the function submitCategory gets called twice. After much analysis found that i had two js files included and removing one of them made the function getting called only once.
 meaning
 when i have included

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="cWed.js"></script>
```

submitCategory function gets called twice

and when i remove one of them and include

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

submitCategory function gets called only once.

Why is it like this?

2> alert(thisvar.value) should return Handicrafts but it returns undefined. why could this be?

3>what exactly is the meaning of href="javascript:submitCategory(this)"? i have not come across this in any tutorial. and including this here should refer to the element "a" right?

Comment: _"including this here should refer to the element "a" right?"_ yes, that's correct. What is `cWed.js`?

Comment: Please don't use JavaScript within a `href` attribute, rather use a proper `onclick` event handling instead.

Answer (score 0):

<s>1. You do not need to use the qualifier 'javascript:'</s>
2. when you hook the event in html, always try to do it like `event_handler(event)`. Note : event is the event object. and not some random variable here. You can read more about it in numerous places on the web. In your case `varthis` is the event object. to access this element use `varthis.target` and then to get its inner html you can use `varthis.target.innerHTML` 
3. when the function is called you have to either explicitly get the html content of the calling element via the event tag, or just use jquery. You cannot pass variables in the way you think you are passing right now. 
4. if you are actually trying to submit a form, I would recommend hooking the onSubmit event in script rather than HTML and put your custom form submit code there. If you do not need to do anything custom in form submission, you can just put the url of the target server function in the `action` attribute of the form.

Sample code :

```
<form>
    <a href="#" id="submitCategoryLink">Submit Category</a>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submitCategoryLink').on('click', function (e) {
        alert(e.target.innerHTML)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: When you put a script in `href`, you **do** need to use the `javascript:` qualifier. You don't need it in `onclick`.

Comment: hey codetantrik
actually i am passing this pointer to event handler so its actually the pointer to element and is same as event.target. so i need not do varthis.target.innerHTML and infact it wont work if i do that.
With regards to your alternative solution, its not actually one <a> link attribute i have. i have some twenty or so and dynamically may get added so i need the this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you haven't posted the contents of `cWed.js` it's difficult to know why you're getting a double submission, but my guess is that it contains a `click` handler of its own, which is duplicating the default handler.
2. The reason `varthis.value` doesn't work is because `.value` is only used for `<input>` and `<select>` elements, it contains the value that the user entered or selected from the menu. To get the text content of an element you should use `.innerHTML`.
3. A URI that begins with `javascript:` means that instead of fetching a page from a network location, the browser should execute the Javascript code after that prefix. It's not an officially recognized URI scheme (there was an Internet-Draft RFC, but it expired 2 years ago) , but all browsers support it.
4. When code is executing from a `javascript:` URI, `this` is the window, not the element that was clicked on. You need to use an `onclick` handler to get `this` set to the element.

The following works:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="submitCategory(this); return false;" >Handicrafts</a>

function submitCategory(varthis)
{   
    alert(varthis.innerHTML);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/RtHpc/5/)

Comment: hi barmar
Thanks for ur help. However it didn work even for tagName, innerHTML, nodeValue